# yFiles Graphsource alternative(js or python) for "DAGs" or "networks"

Tags: python, d3.js, graph, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

yFiles have this graph, I'm very interesting in applying something similar in a python/JS environment.
http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.3/demos/databinding/demo.yfiles.binding.interactivegraphsource/index.html

It has to be JS or Python. 
 Do notice is not a tree-structure, as it has interconnectivity, as the possibity multiple parent nodes. So it is more of DAG - Directec Acyclic Graf or network graf.

I can't seem to find anything that is as simple and symmetric as this module.

I've lookup DAG's and networks for python and js, but can't seem to find anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3

It is great. Has two weaknesses:

Bad integration with IE and you cannot make it collabsible (what I know of)

Comment: I used Vis.js as seen daggenerator.com

Comment: Internet Explorer is hopefully no longer a factor ;-)